# write to a specific cell in excel from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

Does anyone know a way to write to a specific cell in to an existing excel file using nodejs.
Reading specific cells from an existing excel file is not a problem for me.

I have tried exceljs and kexcel without any success.

Comment: Is exceljs and the command `worksheet.getCell("C3").value = "VAL";` not good enough for you? [Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#handling-individual-cells)

Comment: The problem comes after the new value has been entered. In the file I use the new value (A1) to calculate another value in B1. Excel just ignores the new value in A1.

Comment: And? What is the problem?